# Chrome Browser "Continue where you left off" is no longer working

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using the latest stable version of Chrome Browser 83 on Windows 7 (Version 83.0.4103.61)

I've always made use of the Chrome Browser setting "continue where you left off" so that all my previously open tabs re-open when I start Chrome Browser.

It's recently stopped re-opening all my previously open tabs after I restart Windows. Instead I now get a single blank Tab. To force Chrome to re-open all my previously open Tabs I then have to T. But all my Tab Groups are lost each time!

This is what I've tried;
1. Uninstalling and re-installing Chrome Browser
2. Creating a new Windows Profile

neither have solved the problem.

I'd assumed maybe Chrome 83 no longer supported Windows 7 but I see this isn't the case and Google are supporting Chrome use on Windows 7 until at least mid 2021.

Can anyone help, it seems such a small issue yet has a big impact on productivity since I lose the Tab Groups from my last session.

Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but it is probably on-topic at [su].

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Disabled Chrome Advanced setting "Continue running background apps when chrome is closed".